# VSCode color themes broken after the latest update (1.78, April 2023)

Tags: visual-studio-code

After the latest 1.78 update all color themes including official ones started to look weird. Is it the same for you? Is it a bug or the new VSCode interface?

Before (1.77.3):
[Before (1.77.3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmzUR.jpg)

After (1.78.2):
[After (1.78.2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox2g7.jpg)

I tried a lot of different themes. Light ones seem to work as before and dark ones now have these strange looks.

Comment: Voting to close - this question would be a better fit over on the VSCode discussion forum on github. While the question is legitimate, it falls outside of the scope of SO.

Comment: 1) does this happen for all your themes? 2) How did you install VS Code? Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in the command palette) into your question post.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code team helped to solve this problem. You have to disable hardware acceleration to fix these artifacts. Follow instructions here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183353